# PHP - catch an exception within an included document

Tags: php, exception, nested, include, try-catch

I have a number of files that are included (with "include_once") in my code and I want to control exceptions at the top level of my "index" file.

But, try/catch statements do not capture exceptions generated in an included file. For instance, an exception in my children files will be unhandled.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

**index.php:**

```
try 
{
    include_once( "child.php" );
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{    
        // do something....
}
```

**child.php**

```
throw new Exception ("error!");
```

Comment: A ";" is missing at the end of the include_once and at the end of your exception.

Comment: Thanks. the code above in dummy and only for the purpose of explaining. My question is more, "a try/catch statement exists in index.php. How do I capture an error in my included child.php from the parent index.php file?"

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

index.php

```
<?php
try 
{
    include_once( "child.php" );
} catch(Exception $e) {    
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

child.php

```
<?php

throw new Exception ("error!");
```